# Using Chromecast as a security device

Tags: chromecast

I have google chromecast connected to my TV at home.  I am wondering if I can use it as a security device akin to auto timers that turn on and off lights in the house.

Can you play a video on the chromecast connected to a TV in the house if you are out of the house?

Comment: Currently the apps on the Chromecast are closed to only certan developers.  Do you even have the hardware to do this?

Comment: @Ramhound, I do not know if I have the hardware to be in developer mode.  I got creative to get what I wanted done.

Comment: That is the simplest problem with your idea to resolve.  You now need hardware ( light switches ) that connect to the internet.

Comment: You need to be on the same local area network to stream content to your chromecast. That said, you'd either have to leave your tv running all day (in which case, what difference does it make what content is playing), or devise some method for turning your tv on/off on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it a security device. It fakes activity in the house. Chromecast wouldn't be required to do this. There are lots of people selling X10 based home networking modules which will turn off and on lights based on computer controls. The TV is only tricky because most now use soft power. X10 had solutions for driving an IR remote and all of the devices from a PC attached to one of the modules. X10 works by using the in house power grid as a carrier for its signal. it wont work across a UPS, and it wont work across the two sides of the electrical panel without a bridging module installed.